# how to stop return from js function till all ajax finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function processData(data) {
    //some processing 
    return data;
}
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': api1,
        'data': {
            'use': "200"
        },
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            'url': api2,
            'data': {
                'use': data.ud;
            },
            'dataType': 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            processData(data);
        });
    });
return;
}
function main() {
    test.done(function (data) {
        parse(data);
    });
}
```

I want to wait till nested ajax finish in test() before return. aync=false is one way but as some said it is not good option.  What can be good solution for it.

1) Result of one ajax is used in other call as input so when() cannot be used which execute call parallel

2) Return will get executed first before 2nd ajax complete and its call back is executed. Sure 2ned ajax call back will get executed but before that test is returned and its done is called from main.

Comment: Rearrange your code so that parse is called inside the success handler of second AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

**Description:** Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `ajax` call from test and use done with call.

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': api1,
        'data': {
            'use': "200"
        },
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        return $.ajax({
            'url': api2,
            'data': {
                'use': data.ud;
            },
            'dataType': 'json'
        });
    });
}

function main() {        
    test.done(function (data) {
        processData(data);
        parse(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`async: false` is bad idea because ajax isn't meant to be blocking. Without `async: false` you cannot stop the function from returning. A better solution would be using `Deferred` object. You code can be improved like this.

```
function processData(data) {
  return data;
}

function test() {
  // what is being returned here is a deferred object
  // see http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/
  return $.ajax().then(function (data) {
    return $.ajax().then(function (data) {
      return processData(data);
    });
  });
}

function main() {
  // you can't stop test from returning, but you can used the return Deferred object
  test().done(function (finalData) {
    // processData(data) in test will be available as `finalData` here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try this jQuery plugin created by me. 
I hope it could make the ajax call chain easier.
[jQuery.chain](http://plugins.jquery.com/chain/)

`$.chain(ajaxfunc,parse, processData).then(success, failure);`

you could find the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lifecube/jt2Fr/)